# How to include Javascript files into shopware5 theme

Tags: javascript, shopware

I am unable to add javascript files to my first Shopware5 theme.  I tried the following method given in one of online articles.
https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/theme-startup-guide/ 
I added my js files into the array on Theme.php file and upload javascript files to the ‘frontend/_public/src/js’

```
/** @var array Defines the files which should be compiled by the
javascript compressor */
protected $javascript = array(
'src/js/jquery.my-plugin.js'
);
```

However the above array was not avilable on my Theme.php file but I added my js files into the array and tried loading it on my theme. I cleared all my caches when I checked the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear all caches and also do a re-compile of the theme. Have in mind that you have to place the js into `frontend/_public`.

The full path of your js-files should be `themes/YourTheme/frontend/_public/src/js/jquery.my-plugin.js`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You also I think need to take care of where you put the scripts file, in the parent or in the child theme, if you inherited some other theme.